Nesting inside :is and :where pseudo-class selectors
Consider the following HTML and CSS code:


.main :is(section p) {
  background: darkcyan;
}
<section class="main">
  <p>Hello</p>
</section>



I expect that the paragraph should not be selected, as the section is not a descendant of an element with the class .main. However, the paragraph still gets selected.
Why does the paragraph get selected? What is the intended use case for this behavior with the :is() selector?

Try removing the space between .main and :is since this is changing the outcome. once removed then it should match your expectation.

Although kinda relevant there is no mention of :where in your question.

Lets consider your overall selector .main :is(section p).
It's trying to select a p that is a descendant of a section which is in itself is a descendant of an element with the class of .main.
Thus the p will be selected because it is a descendant of .main and it is a descendant of a section so "both` selectors in your overall selector are correct.
See the difference when we wrap the paragraph in a div instead.


.main :is(section p) {
  background: darkcyan;
}

.main {
  padding: .25em;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
<section class="main">
  <p>Hello</p>
</section>

<div class="main">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>



